# Apache Nifi - store lines into 1 file

Tags: json, apache-nifi

Using Apache Nifi, I created a flow that read a Json file and splits it line by line in order to verify if the content is correct. After that I have 2 outputs: 1 - for successful line and 2-for unsuccessful ones and the output is a Json file.

For the moment, all the lines are stored into separate files but what I want to do is to store each "good" line into 1 file and each "bad" one in another.

What processor should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RouteText processor was designed for exactly what you are trying to do. It allows you to route lines of text to different relationships based on expressions you create. It bundles the lines from each FlowFile together for each relationship.

You can see the documentation for it here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteText/index.html

You can get an example template (doing almost exactly what you would like to do) using RouteText here: https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/nifi-templates/blob/master/templates/SplitRouteMergeVsRouteText.xml